# CakePHP 1.3 and Link to subdomain

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, html-helper

I've been to the darkest corners of the internet, searching for an answer to this.

It's such a simple question, but I just can't make a link to a subdomain using Cake's HTML helper. I know that in 2.0, you can do $this->html->link('Subdomain', array('subdomain' => 'hellosub', 'controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar')); but I'm rolling with 1.3..

Thanks :-)

Comment: It's $this->Html not $this->html

Comment: ... Idiot :-) I use $this->html, and it's working fine.